# React Native with Next.js Backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, next.js, backend

I am quite a newbie to react native. Is it possible to use a Next.js backend with a react native app? I know its possible to use react native with backends such as Node+Express, but I personally prefer where Next.js is heading with its new releases, and would like to use it for a web app too.

Comment: This is covered in the official documentation https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-nextjs/

Answer (score 3):

React is

> a library for building UIs

Next by its website definition is

> The React Framework for Production

so if you want to build a web application that runs on the browser you can use react or next, Next has added some nice features like server-side rendering and the ability to have js backend on the project too.

on the other hand, React-Native definition:

> Create native apps for Android and iOS using React

and you can use React Native when you want to produce a native application.

so, here you decided to create a native application with React-Native. you should look at this concern separately from creating your backend server. Besides this native application you want to create a backend server, what do you need for that backend server and what do you expect from that server, when you specify some answers for these questions and a little search you can choose a good framework for building that web server.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s possible. Implementing a framework right now and it’s my next step. As I go mobile first I have to make sure layouts are matching.

It’s easy to swap components (ReactNative/NextJS) according to target device.

It’s a bit a pain to setup, I think a (Meta-) MonoRepo with PNPM could be a good idea. If you have some news let me know. Who knows, I’m looking anyway for someone planning the same and it’s enthusiastic about it.

My framework was implemented in NativeJS, then CoffeeScript, then TypeScript, now NextJS/ReactNative, way better match IMO than Dart (well, quick evaluation), there are always ways to do everything. just ones and zeros

I’m supporting Bulma, Tailwind, Storybook, Figma, many more coming, going as generic as possible. Not my first one. When PHP4 had its best days, I had a working CMS online (and threw it after Async Requests came up. Then threw it again when NodeJS came up, then MeteorJS. yeah, think I’m ready soon to finally release again